# ¿Cómo verificar que el valor de una variable String es un Integer en Java?

Tags: java

Necesito convertir un `String` a `Integer` pero primero tengo que asegurarme que es un numero.
En C# utilizo [`int.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) o `"".All(Char.IsNumber)` pero al parecer no existe tales cosas en Java.

Comment: El metodo para validar si es un numero, puede ser una libreria third-party, o mejor que sea hecha a mano?

Comment: A mano. No quiero agregar una libreria  solo para saber si un string es un numero.

Comment: Si solo quieres comprar un número o recorrer la cadena , con un método boolean: ' return Character.isDigit(valor);'

Comment: Dicho método está siempre implícito al llamar `parseInt`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Codigo

```
package javaapplication7;

public class JavaApplication7 {

    public static boolean isNumeric(String cadena) {

        boolean resultado;

        try {
            Integer.parseInt(cadena);
            resultado = true;
        } catch (NumberFormatException excepcion) {
            resultado = false;
        }

        return resultado;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String cadena = "500";
        int numero;

        if (isNumeric(cadena) == true) {
            numero = Integer.parseInt(cadena);
            System.out.println("Numero: " + numero);
        } else {
            System.out.println("No es un numero");
        }

    }

}
```

### Resultado

**Numero**

> **cadena**: 500
>
> Numero: 500

**Cadena**

> **cadena**: Hola mundo
>
> No es un numero

### Explicacion

Usando la posible excepcion que lanza la funcion [Integer.parseInt()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/number_parseint.htm), basta encerrar en un  `try/catch` la conversion de la cadena a numero.

Cuando la excepcion de tipo `NumberFormatException` ocurra, entonces **determinamos que la conversion ha fallado** y por lo tanto la cadena que se intento convertir, no es un numero, retornando `FALSE`. En caso contrario nos retorna un `TRUE`.

### [Ver ejemplo](https://tio.run/##jZA/T8MwEMX3fopTpkSIKAsLVUeQGGDpWHW4ONfgNrEj@1xRoX72cKEJ@QMDt5yte37v/DviGe9tQ@ZYnNq2CXmlFagKvYdX1AY@VyuQ6geekaXl1laEBrR/CzU5reItO21KUFiQwWR41dWgdeRDxVjY9ThjdxEpTOrFMJXk0gadJ7nEveN6pvrxgo14BBqnV1mB1TvEslhO7tm6GvnpQ1HD2hqg7qTklCxyp44HrPzUctzXEQc3@8pEMEd0trqAWgj2aHZ7QFf6GZoZNAnuBLtsP0Zrw2A6wlNo@gDxCH4gvrmRWP7r9lq8/wd2e/FMdWoDp43sxpWJo@8k@wgR3PV2yZQ3CaxF6J8uFshDML1FlPwCLO3atu1Dln0B)

Comment: `TryParse` está implícito ya que `parseInt` arroja una excepción que cambia el flujo del programa automáticamente, cualquier otra implementación es redudante y poco práctica.

Answer (score 4):

Si no utilizas alguna librería externa que te facilite la funcionalidad, lo mejor es definir una clase de utilidades con un método que haga la comprobación, similar a:

```
public boolean isInteger(String numero){
    try{
        Integer.parseInt(numero);
        return true;
    }catch(NumberFormatException e){
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

La razón por la que no existe `TryParse`  es porque ya está implícito.

Si revisas el prototipo de [`Integer.parseInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) podrás ver que el método arroja una excepción al pasarle una cadena sin un entero válido.

```
public static int parseInt(String s)
                    throws NumberFormatException
```

*NumberFormatException* es una excepción comprobada. Java tiene dos tipos excepciones: comprabadas y no comprabadas, el primer tipo obliga *SIEMPRE* a encerrar la llamada con los bloques `try...catch` al método que la arroja, mientras que el segundo tipo no.

Si analizamos el flujo en *C#*

```
int resultado;
if (Int32.TryParse(cadena, out resultado))
  {
    // TODO1
  }
else 
  {
    // TODO2
  }
```

El equivalente en *Java* es

```
try
  {
    int resultado = Integer.parseInt(cadena);
    // TODO1
  } 
catch(NumberFormatException e) 
  {
    // TODO2
  }
```

Como puedes ver `TryParse` está implícito ya que  `parseInt` arroja una excepción, que cambia el flujo del programa automáticamente.

**P.D**

Se desaconseja cualquier implementación de `TryParse` ya que a diferencia de *C#* los tipos primitivos en *Java*, siempre son pasados por valor, esto quiere decir que el método planteado requeriría analizar 2 veces la cadena, una para retornarte si la cadena efectivamente contiene un entero y la otra para obtener su valor, lo cuál es absurdo.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Ver si un String contiene un numero
      public static boolean verificarNumeros(String numOlet){
            boolean num=false;
            if((numOlet.contains("0")||numOlet.contains("1")||numOlet.contains("2"))||numOlet.contains("3")||numOlet.contains("4")||numOlet.contains("5")||numOlet.contains("6")||numOlet.contains("7")||numOlet.contains("8")||numOlet.contains("9")||numOlet.contains("!")){
                System.out.println("tiene numeros");
                num=true;
            }
        return num;

        }
```

Comment: Bienvenido!!! tene en cuenta que esta es un pregunta vieja, y lo que estas contestando no resuelve exactamente el problema planteado (vos decis si un string tiene un numero, y la pregunta es si se puede transformar a numero) En tu caso, "hola1" devuelve true, pero no se puede transformar a numero. Mira por favor el [tour] y tambien [answer]

Answer (score -1):

Una alternativa para comprobar que el String solo posee digitos como caracter siempre es recorre el String y comprobarlo asi te evitas la excepción.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String nullType = null;
    String integerType = "123434";
    String characterType = "adsf4";

    System.out.println(isInteger(nullType));
    System.out.println(isInteger(integerType));
    System.out.println(isInteger(characterType));

}

public static boolean isInteger(String source) {

    if (source == null || source.isEmpty())
        return false;

    int index = 0;
    while (index < source.length() && 
            Character.isDigit(source.charAt(index))) {
        index++;
    }
    return index == source.length();
}
```

Edit: Solo vale para numeros positivos en el caso de negativos tendrias que hacer una compracion extra para el simbolo de negativo.