# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que el usuario solo ingrese numeros y lo intente de nuevo en Java?

Tags: java, while, try-catch, scanner

Se supone que el funcionamiento es así, el programa solicita un numero y el usuario debe ingresarlo, en dado caso que el usuario ingrese una letra, un numero menor a 0 o no ingrese nada, le salte un error y le mencione que lo intente de nuevo, dándole al usuario intentos infinitos.

Lo he intentado pero solo consigo un bucle infinito dentro del catch, ¿me podrían ayudar?

```java
public static void numero(){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i, numero;
        
        System.out.print("Ingresa solamente un numero: ");
        while(true){
            try {
                numero = in.nextInt();
                if(numero > 0){
                    break;
                } else {
                    System.out.print("Error, intenta de nuevo: ");
                }
            } catch (Exception e){
                System.out.print("Error, intenta de nuevo: ");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static boolean isNumeric(String cadena) {

        boolean verdad;

        try {
            Integer.parseInt(cadena);
            verdad = true;
        } catch (NumberFormatException excepcion) {
            verdad = false;
        }

        return verdad;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       
       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int  numero;
        System.out.println("Ingresa solamente un numero:");
        String cadena= in.nextLine();
        while(isNumeric(cadena)==false ||  Integer.parseInt(cadena)<=0){
            System.out.println("La entrada no era un numero vuelva a intentarlo");
            cadena= in.nextLine();
        }
        
        if (isNumeric(cadena) == true) {
            numero = Integer.parseInt(cadena);
            System.out.println("Numero: " + numero);
        } else {
            System.out.println("No es un numero");
        }
    }
```

Necesitas hacer un método booleano isNumeric para verificar si una cadena x posee un número o letras. Al método se le pasa una cadena, y se verifica que si la misma es un número la bandera booleana seguirá en verdadero, en caso de que no sea un número, se llama a la excepción NumberFormatException se produce cuando intenta analizar una cadena no numérica. Luego en el main solo se invoca el método isNumeric y le pasamos la cadena que entre el usuario.

Puedes revisar tambien este link [https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/92139/cómo-verificar-que-el-valor-de-una-variable-string-es-un-integer-en-java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/92139/c%C3%B3mo-verificar-que-el-valor-de-una-variable-string-es-un-integer-en-java)